# Magento Go: How to display Product description on Homepage/Category page

Tags: magento-go

I am working on a site in Magento Go where I am displaying product listing on Homepage and Category Pages. For reference:

https://vimergy.gostorego.com/

I want to display a small product description under each product. I have created an attribute for the same, but how can I achieve this in Magento Go?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Magento Go is Closed as of February 1st 2015

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Short Description attribute for this purpose.

See a discussion about this here: [How to turn on Short Descriptions?](https://collaborate.magento.com/magento/topics/how_to_turn_on_short_descriptions)

Comment: I am already using short Description attribute for this purpose. Also, I have tried the suggestions posted by you, but it didn't worked for me.